# Ctrl+Shift+F formatting not working in JSP pages

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, alias

I can format my code with the alias Ctrl+Shift+F in JavaScript files, Java classes, but not in JSP pages.

Why? I cannot double click to select text too.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers:

```
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

PS: It is not formatting HTML TAGS in a JSP file.

Before using the shortcut:

[image]

When ctrl+shift+F used to work:

[image]

Comment: Which eclipse do you use (version, package)?

Comment: I am using eclipse: 

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Right click on jsp file -> Open With -> JSP Editor.

Comment: Can you show your jsp content and what you want it to be after formatting it?

Comment: Aleksandr, it is not a pattern or some rules to format that I need. I used to use this shortcut just to organize the text, as I am copying from the template and pasting it.

Comment: does not organize the tags... removing extra space, etc.

Comment: Sure, done, editted the post.

Comment: And as a text so all can copy-paste and hit ctrl-shift-f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just right click on jsp page name in right side's package explorer and select open with jsp editor. Now you should be able to format using ctrl+shift+f. See below attached image:

[image]

Comment: Rakesh, did not work, I still can not select a piece of code and format (indentation).

Comment: up 1 for screenshot.